# Dealing with a lot of (possible) exception to throw using a factory in PHP?

Tags: php, exception, factory

I'm currently writing the code code for interacting with a WebService that return a `status` field, a number describing the fail of the operation. There are twenty `status` values: `10`, `11`, `12`, `20...37`. How would you proper throw exceptions based on the code?

Creating **twenty or more** `CodeXXGatewayException` (where `XX` is code) seems a lot of work and surely not a neat solution:

```
class Code10GatewayException
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Generic Error.', 10);
    }
}

class Code11GatewayException
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('Invalid charset.', 11);
    }
}

// Throw the exception
$class = "My\Exception\Client$statusException";
throw new $class;
```

What about **an exception factory** with a `$reasonMap`? How (usually) people deal with a large number of exceptions in big projects?

```
class GatewayException extends \RuntimeException
{
    public function __construct($code, $reason)
    {
        parent::__construct($reason, $code);
    }
}

class ExceptionFactory
{
    public static $reasonMap = array(
        '10' => 'Generic error',
        '11' => 'Invalid charset',
        // ...
    );
    public static function fromStatus($status)
    {
        return new GatewayException($status, self::$reasonMap[$status] . '.');
    }
}

// Throw the exception
throw new ExceptionFactory::fromStatus($status);
```